# How to set value to radio button when value is coming from API in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, radio-button

I have 3 Radio Buttons

```
<input type="radio" name="rdoType" ng-model="result.visible" value="Gold">Gold
<input type="radio" name="rdoType" ng-model="result.visible" value="Silver">Silver
<input type="radio" name="rdoType" ng-model="result.visible" value="Copper">Copper
```

Now I set default selected Gold by add ng-init

```
<span class="textValue" ng-init="result.visible = 'Gold'>
    <input type="radio" name="rdoType" ng-model="result.visible" value="Gold">Gold
    <input type="radio" name="rdoType" ng-model="result.visible" value="Silver">Silver
    <input type="radio" name="rdoType" ng-model="result.visible" value="Copper">Copper
</span>
```

This sets Gold as a default selected radio button. But
Now while editing this page, I'm getting Silver from API, now how to set Silver as selected radio button.

Comment: Can you make jsfiddle for it?

Answer (score 0):

create a result.visible variable inside controller so that we can assign updated value to it.

SampleController.js

```
function ($scope) {
     var $scope.result =  {
           'visible':Gold;
     }
     var $scope.updateVisible = function () {
          result['visible'] = Silver
     }
}
```

SampleHtml.html

```
<span class="textValue">
    <input type="radio" name="rdoType" ng-model="$ctrl.result.visible" value="Gold">Gold
    <input type="radio" name="rdoType" ng-model="$ctrl.result.visible" value="Silver">Silver
    <input type="radio" name="rdoType" ng-model="$ctrl.result.visible" value="Copper">Copper
</span>
```

See if it helps